# Change parameters of the bootstrap modal window

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in web. This is my bootstrap modal window:

```
<div id="dialog" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Message</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>@Html.TextArea("commentForDecline")</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button title="Ok" class="btn btn-primary ok-request">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a picture: 
[image]
How I can change some parameters of this window? I need to put buttons to the left side of the window (under the text area).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS will left align the buttons for you:

```
.modal-footer{
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're adding that CSS _after_ the bootstrap CSS. See [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/JF8FDDb3pX)...it functions perfectly

Comment: O, thank you! And I have another one question if have a free time: I wanna to change size of this window.

Comment: Sure, [take a look at the docs for sizing modals here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes)